# Add input-tags to an article and create new tag records if it's non-existence in database

Tags: python, django

I have `Tag` and `Article` data models of many-to-many relationships,

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)

class Article(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

When receiving tags inputted from the form, I first check if the tags existing to determine whether or not to create a new one in the database,
and then append all input-tags to an article.

```
#save the new article in database   
if article_form.is_valid():
    article = article_form.save(commit=False)
    article.owner = self.request.user
    article.save()
```

1. create tags which not found in records

   ```
   #compare tags
   input_tags = self.request.POST["tags"]
   input_tags = tags.split(",")
   query_tags = Tag.objects.all()
   #get name list of tab objects
   query_tags = [tag.name for tag in query_tags]
   #create new tabs in TabTable
   for tag in input_tags:
       if tag not in query_tags:
           Tag.objects.create(name=tag, owner=self.request.user)
   ```
2. retrieve input tag objects

   ```
   tag_objs = []
   for input_tag in input_tags:
       try:
           qualified_tab = Tab.object.filter(name=input_tag)[0]
           tag_objs.append(qualified_tab)
   ```
3. append tags to article

   ```
   article.tags.add(*tag_objs)
   ```

This is a routine task, but the solution is cumbersome.

*How to complete such a task elegantly?*

Comment: test the comment system

Comment: test the active status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get_or_create(defaults=None, **kwargs)**

A convenience method for looking up an object with the given kwargs (may be empty if your model has defaults for all fields), creating one if necessary.

Returns a tuple of **(object, created)**, where object is the retrieved or created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

```
if article_form.is_valid():
    article = article_form.save(commit=False)
    article.owner = self.request.user
    article.save()

   # tag list
   input_tags = self.request.POST["tags"]
   input_tags = tags.split(",")

   #create new tabs in TabTable
   for tag in input_tags:
       tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_created(
                           name=tag, 
                           defaults={"owner":self.request.user})
       tag.article_set.add(article)
       #article.tags.add(tag) test
```